# BA - Cancel Domestic Leg of European Flight

Tags: air-travel, british-airways

I have a British Airways booking from GLA to FCO with a stopover in LHR (booked as a single booking).  The booking was a reward booking made with Avios points.  My issue is that I will now be in London on the date of the first leg and therefore only require the second leg.  If I don't fly the first domestic leg, will the second leg to Italy be automatically cancelled?  Also, if I contact them beforehand, would there be additional charges in changing the flight?

Many thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Yes it'll be cancelled, £35 is the change fee for an avios booking

Comment: Be very sure to contact them and change the flight. If you just show up at LHR you might find you can not fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if booked as one through ticket, declining to take the first leg usually results in the second leg being cancelled on BA. [Indeed, this is not reliably the case (some friends did an experiment recently to test this), but unless you are willing to front the cost of a walk up ticket to satiate your curiosity, I advise calling ahead.]

If booked after 28 April, domestic add ons are not longer free and you will get 4500 Avios back. If booked before, domestic add ons were free at this time and no Avios refund will be due.

If you hold Gold Guest List status with BA, the change is free. Otherwise, there is a £35 change fee. http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/executive-club/spending-avios/booking-and-service-fees